# .htaccess to deny every direct acces request except allowing the request to a single folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am using codeigniter and have put the assets folder in the root of the application that contains a `.htaccess` file having the content

> Deny from all

This is causing problems when I want to connect to the assets folder to get the stylesheets etc. So my question here is is there any way that I can allow the access just to that assets folder, that I have?

I have never used `.htacces` files so have a very basic knowlege of it. I did some research on my own as well but I wasn't able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your assets directory add another `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
# /assets/.htaccess
Allow from all
```

And I am assuming in your root directory you have the following (which you will leave):

```
# /.htaccess
Deny from all
```

**Update:** Based on your comment, what you are looking to do is not really possible. The browser needs to have access to your CSS file in order to use it on your page.

Comment: It does work but with a security issue that I can now open any file in assets folder using the link e.g. `http://kamran.dev/Codeigniter/application/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` showed me the whole CSS file. How may I handle this, i.e. disallow the direct access?

Comment: What you are looking to do is not possible then. You must be able to access CSS directly in order for the browser to use them.